# Mongodb: get notified if exist, insert if not exist

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm handling my user register logic with Mongodb. I need insert a user if it is not exist, but get to know if it is already exists before insert, so I can notify the user he has already registered.

The `update` method with `upsert` will not return the result of how many docs have inserted ( I do not . And `findAndModify` method will only find docs after insert. So neither way I'm not able to know if there is already such a doc before I insert.

Is there a way to do this?

#### Update

`update` and `findAndModify` are not good examples. I do not want to update my doc if the user is already exists. I just want to know if the `username` is exists before insert. If not, then insert it.

I'm not using `_id` with insert. Should I use `username` as `_id` and use it to insert?

Comment: You could split your query - one operation strictly updates the collection, the other strictly adds new document(s).

Comment: Use a unique key (on e-mail address or whatever identifies a user) and check for corresponding error code when trying to insert. That's *the* way.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Thanks for the comment. I think it is the right way. Could you please write an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique key (on e-mail address or whatever identifies a user) and check for corresponding error code when trying to insert. That's the way. Not just for MongoDB.

```
db.users.createIndex({email: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Now when inserting a duplicate e-mail, check for error codes `11000` and `11001`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use _id as your userid, you can use the save() command.

This will create a new record if there's not one already, otherwise will update the existing record.

It's probably better to check for the user and then selectively update, but this is a down and dirty way of doing things:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Comment: But I don't want to update my record. Just create a new one if not exist.

Comment: Then take the answer from @Prinzhorn!